# Unterschied: "austreten" und "abtreten" im Sinne von "abnutzen"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich möchte die Unterschiede in der Benutzung beider Wörter in der Bedeutung von "abnutzen" wissen.

Comment: Ich kenne die Wörter nicht im Sinne von "abnutzen". Wie kommst Du darauf, dass dies ihre Bedeutung wäre, woher hast Du das? Was sagen die Wörterbücher? Wieso hilft es nicht weiter?

Answer (score 6):

Die sinnvollste grammatikalische Form ist für diese Bedeutungen das Partizip Perfekt, weil es sich um Prozesse handelt, die ziemlich lange dauern.

- *ausgetreten* können neben Schuhen auch Treppenstufen sein, deren Kante im Lauf der Jahrzehnte eine Rundung nach unten erfährt.
- *abgetreten* habe ich auch schon von Fußabstreifern, Teppichen (oder allgemeiner: Bodenbelägen) insgesamt oder speziell dem Teppichflor und den Fransen gelesen.

Answer (score 5):

Wenn es um die Bedeutung "abnutzen" geht, werden sowohl "austreten" als auch "abtreten" in aller Regel bei Schuhen verwendet, und das meistens im Passiv der Vergangenheit.

Wenn Schuhe "ausgetreten sind", dann haben sie sich durch die Benutzung geweitet oder sonstwie die Form verändert. Die Schuhe sitzen dann nicht mehr so eng und passgenau, wie sie es am Anfang taten.

Wenn Schuhe "abgetreten sind", geht es mehr um das Äußere der Schuhe. Zum Beispiel kann die Sohle abgenutzt sein.

Answer (score 0):

"Ausgetreten" umschreibt Beschädiung normaler Benutzung zufolge, wogegen "abgetreten" eher bezogen ist auf Folgen von Misbrauch oder besonders rücksichtsloser Nutzung. Auf Schuhe bezogen könnte man sogar von "ausgewohnt" reden, was noch ein Schritt weiter geht.

Beispiele (gemackshalber für Schuhe):
"Ausgetreten" sind gute Wanderschuhe erst nach einige Jahrzehnter Benutzung, trotz Pflege und Wartung.
"Abgetreten" sind Hallenschuhe meistens schon nach ein einzige Bergwanderung, denn dafür sind sie nicht gedacht.
"Ausgewohnt" sind Schuhe erst wenn sie fast schon unbrauchbar sind, man sich davon aber um meistens sentimentale Gründe nicht verabschieden kann, so wie die Stiefel von Don Johnson in "Harley Davidson and the Marlboro man".

(Feel free to edit into German)